# Absence of leading or trailing space in regex invalidates search

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to search different types of dates in my strings using regex.

```
import re

txt1 = "The date is 3-Dec "
txt2 = "The date is3-Dec "
txt3 = "The date is 3-Dec"
txt4 = "The date is Dec-20"
txt5 = "The date isDec-20"

regx = r"(?:\d{2}|\d{1}|\d{0})(?:[,| ,|, |-|/|\\|\s|\d{0}])(?:%s)(?:[,| ,|, |-|/|\\|\s|\d{0}])(?:\d{4}|\d{2}|\d{0})" % '|'.join(['Nov', 'Dec'])

x1 = re.findall(regx, txt1)
print(x1)
x2 = re.findall(regx, txt2)
print(x2)
x3 = re.findall(regx, txt3)
print(x3) # empty
x4 = re.findall(regx, txt4)
print(x4)
x5 = re.findall(regx, txt5)
print(x5) # empty
```

Could someone help why `txt3` and `txt5` are not working? Basically following portion of regex is not working when there is no leading or trailing space for date `(?:[,| ,|, |-|/|\\|\s|\d{0}])`

Comment: `[...]` is a character class and you shouldn't confuse it with `(...|...)`.

Comment: @iBug replacing `(?:[,| ,|, |-|/|\\|\s|\d{0}])` with `(?:,| ,|, |-|/|\\|\s|\d{0})` doesn't seem to help

Comment: You are expecting one of the sub-regex to match. If you're looking for "something else", `\b` (word boundary) is an option to look into. Also, if you want to match `isDec-20` (which isn't really any good formatting), you probably want to drop everything around entirely.

Comment: one of the sub-regex is `\d{0}` and it should match no leading/trailing space. No? Because if I get rid of `(?:[,| ,|, |-|/|\\|\s|\d{0}])` it works matching `d{0}` from first sub-regex

Comment: Replacing *both* wrong uses of `[...]` works for me. Is anything else wrong?

Comment: @iBug would you mind copy-pasting your modified regex?

Comment: `regx = r"(?:\d{2}|\d{1}|\d{0})(?:,| ,|, |-|/|\\|\s|\d{0})(?:%s)(?:,| ,|, |-|/|\\|\s|\d{0})(?:\d{4}|\d{2}|\d{0})" % '|'.join(['Nov', 'Dec'])` Just deleted two wrong pairs of `[]`. Nothing else was changed.

Comment: The character classes that you use expect to match a single char from the listed. You could make the pattern a bit more specific and omit some of the superfluous parts https://ideone.com/B9eY1T

Comment: @iBug thanks. Now I found the mistake.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yours definitely looks more elegant. I am new to regex so trying to understand your composition.

Comment: @Thefourthbird `[\s,/\\-]` in your regex imply space, comma, forward slash, back slash and dash. How does it account for no character?

Comment: @Gerry Make it optional using a question mark `[\s,/\\-]?`

Comment: ok and  `(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` says match any number between 1-9  OR `[12]\d` OR `3[01]`. what does last two sub-regex imply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
months = ['Nov', 'Dec']
date_rx = r'(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])'
month_rx = r'(?:{})'.format('|'.join(months))
sep_rx = r'[\s,/\\-]'
regx = r"(?<!\d){0}{2}{1}|{1}{2}{0}(?!\d)".format(date_rx, month_rx, sep_rx)
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/akrUij). The regex is

```py
(?<!\d)(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\s,/\\-](?:Nov|Dec)|(?:Nov|Dec)[\s,/\\-](?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hNLDXw/1).

**Regex part details**:

- `(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` (`date_rx`) - a non-zero digit, `10` to `29` or `30` or `31`
- `(?:Nov|Dec)` (`month_rx`) - `Nov` or `Dec`
- `[\s,/\\-]` (`sep_rx`) - whitespace, comma, slash, backslash or a hyphen.

The negative lookbehind `(?<!\d)` makes sure there is no digit immediately to the left of the current location and the negative lookahead `(?!\d)` makes sure there is no digit immediately to the right of the current location.